# Modal backdrop not shown using Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the *modal* plugin from Bootstrap and for some reason the *backdrop* is not showing.

When I [check same code on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal&stacked=h) I notice a `div` is generated every time a modal opens:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

I got the exact same code as on W3Schools but this `div` is not generated on my site.

How can I fix that?

Comment: show some more code so that we can start from

Comment: @BhavinShah I got exactly the same code as on w3schools. And included bootstrap.min.js

Comment: okay.. so did you include `modal-backdrop fade in` CSS?

Comment: Yeah I did.....

Comment: Any console errors?

Answer (score 11):

This happened to me when I used the wrong method to open the modal. I had

```
$('#myModal').show()
```

when of course it should be

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Another symptom of using the wrong method, in addition to the semi-opaque backdrop not showing, was the close button in the modal also did not work.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Have been trying to figure out where I tripped up for so long.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether CSS properties are overridden or not by inspecting `<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>` element. Mostly this could be a CSS issue caused by an override.

Comment: That div is not generated when I open a modal. That is the issue.

Comment: Can you show more details, how the modal is triggered and how bootstrap is included into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce this, as the w3 school examples work fine.

Verify the following. This might cause the issue:

- It's good practice to put the `<div class="modal">..` at the end of
  the file or before `</body>`
- If any other css class is overriding the modal-backdrop class
- if jquery and bootstrap JS are added properly

Get the modal from
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples